# Is there a way to mock functions from a jasmine Spy

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, karma-jasmine, spy

I'm using jasmine to create a spy object, and returning an object, can I mock functions from the object I'm returning?

For example:

```js
let mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['fun']);
mockService.fun.and.returnValue({value: 1});
```

I'm trying to mock the get function in this example:

```js
let x = service.fun();
x.get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `jasmine.createSpyObj()` method to create spy obj for the return value of `service.fun()`.

```js
describe('70304592', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const funSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(['get']);
    funSpy.get.and.returnValue('1');
    let serviceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(['fun']);
    serviceSpy.fun.and.returnValue(funSpy);
    const x = serviceSpy.fun();
    expect(x.get()).toBe('1');
  });
});
```

**update**: If the object has properties and methods, you can create spy obj like this:

```js
describe('70304592', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const funSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('fun', {}, { get: jasmine.createSpy(), value: 'please upvote xD' });
    funSpy.get.and.returnValue('1');
    let serviceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(['fun']);
    serviceSpy.fun.and.returnValue(funSpy);
    const x = serviceSpy.fun();
    expect(x.get()).toBe('1');
    expect(x.value).toBe('please upvote xD');
  });
});
```

See [Spying on properties](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/spying_on_properties) doc

Comment: Didn't think to return a spy! Thank you!

Comment: Hi just a quick follow up question, if in this example i want to do x.get(), but also have a variable from the x object, for example x.value. How to can i have both? (x.get() and x.value)

Comment: @zechuegui Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you!! I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation. When i do i will comeback!